# str.find(s) fails if str starts with s

Tags: python

This code is supposed to count number of occurances of 'bob' in string s.
The code works fine if s does not start with 'bob' , which i am looking for to count.
But once the s starts with 'bob' it cant find anything. al all. Returns -1. why is that?

```
beg = 0
count = 0
s = "boboxboobt"

while beg >=0 :
    beg = s.find('bob', beg)
    print("beg is :", beg)
    if beg > 0:
        count +=1
        beg +=2
        print('Count is:', count)
        print("beg is :", beg)

    else:
        print('negativ')
        break
print('count ', count)
```

Comment: `"boboxboobt".find('bob', 0)` returns `0`, not `-1`.

Comment: The condition `if beg > 0` should likely be `if beg >= 0`, as `beg == 0` is what you'll get when `s` begins with `bob`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it doesn't return `-1`, it returns *zero*, which is perfectly valid, so the first condition should be:

```
if beg >= 0:
```

Answer (score 1):

`"boboxboobt".find('bob', 0)` returns `0`, not `-1`:

```
>>> s = "boboxboobt"
>>> s.find('bob', 0)
0
```

You have an off-by-one error in your code instead:

```
if beg > 0:
```

This *excludes* the `beg = 0` case. Turn that into:

```
if beg > -1:
```

Comment: I see. thanks. count does not work since it will not count if bobob happens.

Comment: @BillyJhon: right, I missed that you wanted overlapping occurences.